# Is there a feature to place a Netlify site under construction?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I have a single-page application (SPA) built with React, which is currently hosted on Netlify. I have a need to temporarily display an "Under Construction" message to visitors, essentially putting the site in a maintenance or pre-launch mode. Does Netlify specifically let you do this?

I tried looking for a feature in Netlify. I know I can do it with React but I am wondering if this feature exist or if there is a way to not avoid the code.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure Netlify offers that feature. But what you can do is create a branch `under-construction` for the *maintenance mode* feature (assuming your repository is directly linked to your Netlify account) and you can always publish the deployed branch on Netlify when you want to switch to *maintenance mode*

Comment: My repository is linked. Is this related to branch splitting in Netlify?

Comment: No, It's not. This is just having a separate branch for maintenance mode and you can always publish. If you need more explanation let me know

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a support guide for doing exactly this - which will work regardless of whether your repo is linked to netlify or not:   https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-what-s-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-temporary-maintenance-page-for-my-site/338 .  This allows you to pre-deploy the maintenance page to browse it as a preview and confirm it looks like you want, and then/also publish it on demand, or perhaps even automate the publishing/unpublishing of it, based on a pre-planned timetable or in reaction to something like another party's statuspage via this API call:  https://open-api.netlify.com/#tag/deploy/operation/restoreSiteDeploy